# Send/receive events without related data via Stream in Dart

Tags: dart

I would like to use something like `StreamController<null>` and `Stream<null>`, but it is impossible to pass `null` as type for generics. 
In other words I need to send/receive only the fact that events occurred, with no related data.

How it can be made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it as generic type argument but `null` is a value and `Null` is a type. If you want null use `<Null>` instead of `null`.

Try it in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/5a727bf336534db3b2e3)

```
import 'dart:async';
main() {
  StreamController<Null> c = new StreamController<Null>();
  c.stream.listen(print);
  c.add(null);
  c.add(null);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You are right, it is my mistake.  `Null` should used instead of `null` in such case.